# Reroute IP through another country

Tags: unix, terminal, ip

How can I route my IP through another country? For example, right now I am in France, and I would like an IP to access URL's through a US IP.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

Find a mate in the US who can setup an SSH Tunnel for you to connect to from france. Most decent dd-wrt/tomato routers can do this.